# Only catching BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast if application already running (Android emulator, Lollipop)

Tags: android, broadcast, boot

Please help me figure out why my app isn't receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast message unless my app is already running.

My goal is for my application to automatically start up as soon as the device is finished booting (start my GUI).  My approach is to catch the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and then start my main activity from inside the onReceive() method.

The problem is my app only catches the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast if it's already running.  What I'm expecting is the OS to start my applications process and call the onReceive() entry point when the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent.  Can someone help me figure out where I've gone wrong? I'm thinking my error is likely in my AndroidManifest.xml file,but I'm not sure what I'm missing *(my first ever Android project)*.

I'm using the Android Studio emulator, Lollipop on a Nexus 5.  The emulator is set to "Do not launch activity" on boot-up since this is how real hardware would work.

I'm sending the broadcast to the emulator like this, and I do catch it if my app is already running:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.matt.catchbootcompletebroadcast
```

My guess is my problem is in my manifest file, here it is (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.matt.catchbootcompletebroadcast" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my onReceive class:

```
    package com.example.matt.catchbootcompletebroadcast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Created by matt on 8/20/2015.
 * To send broadcast: adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.matt.catchbootcompletebroadcast
 */
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("ReceivedABroadcast", "Received A Broadcast");
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            Log.d("ReceivedBootCompleted", "Received BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast");
        }
        // Open the main activity to this application
        Intent startApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(startApp);
    }

}
```

All tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has your app been launched at least once by the user after being installed?

Comment: This seems perfectly correct to me try launching it on an android device.

Comment: Have you tried it to the real device?

Comment: Thanks guys.  @Karakuri, yes in that it ran the app, then powered off the emulator and powered it back on again via android studio.  But this might re-install the app automatically, which I'm guessing resets it to never being run before.  The emulator is set to NOT clear user data on reboot.  I tried rebooting the emulator via "adb reboot", but the emulator hangs at a black screen as soon as the OS has shut down.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH and KISHORE - I have not tried it on real hardware yet.  My only real device is my locked phone, I'll try to get my hands on a real device and give it a go.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

Try launching it on an android device. If that doesn't work try this: in the Android Manifest file for the `<receiver>` tag remove the `enabled` and `exported` part. And inside the Receiver class remove the `if` statement.

Reason: Because you have already filtered the intents received by the broadcast receiver the `if` statement is pretty much useless. If all this doesn't work this may help you:           Android declared that the following actions have to be written programmatically only.  And I beleive that list contains `intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`  so maybe it will work if you declare the receiver programmatically. To me it looks right. But I suppose these ideas may be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get my hands on real hardware and give it a go.

Comment: Ok also try the other ideas and if you wish send me the compiled apk I have a device. I could test it if you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!  Can I send you the apk through this web site, or would I need to host it on a 3rd party site and share a link?

Comment: Most likely you have to use 3rd party apps like Google drive or mediafire as I don't think you can post an apk directly via stack overflow itself.

Comment: I've obtained some real hardware to test this on, I will report back my results once I figure out how to get it installed there.  Thank you again for being willing to test this for me, I appreciate it!

Comment: Simply connect your phone to the computer using the USB cable and be debug it by clicking the run button and  selecting your device in the list. Also switch on USB debugging on your phone and allow your computer to access it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, my app DID attempt to start on the real hardware after rebooting!  So the solution there was (1) Do it on real hardware, and (2) open the app manually at least once before rebooting.  Now I get a crash when I try to start my GUI from my onReceive().  If you look at my code above, I believe it's crashing on the context.startActivity() inside onReceive().  My ultimate goal is to have it automatically open my MainAction() GUI when the device boots.  Am I doing something obviously wrong inside my onReceive()?

Comment: You helped me solve it, thank you!  The catlog was the key, I didn't know that was a thing on the real device.  The log showed "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. "  So in my code just before context.startActivity() I added "startApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);" and presto my app starts up when the device is finished booting.  Thank you very much for your help, I very greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome and a you should probably if ever your application crashes without reason. It happens to me a lot. Just check the logcat it almost always work for me. You forgot to declare activity in the Manifest or a permission or something. It's really useful. And one more thing to help your user try adding another flag `startApp.setFlags (INTENT.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)`

Answer (score 1):

To summarize all the comments above, in addition the code in my first post, the solution was:

(1) I could only get my app to receive BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast on boot-up with real hardware.  Maybe it's possible with the emulator, but the emulator didn't work for me.
(2) Open the application once manually before rebooting.  After this, the application will automatically start after every boot.

(3) My onReceive() had to include the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag or the app would crash when it tried to start.  My onReceive() ended up looking like this:

```
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("ReceivedABroadcast", "Received A Broadcast");
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            Log.d("ReceivedBootCompleted", "Received BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast");
        }
        // Open the main activity to this application
        Intent startApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        startApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
        startApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
        context.startActivity(startApp);
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!!

Comment: Just to clarify what you experienced:
(2) Apps must be run once (by user) for any of its receivers to receive any events. This is by design since KitKat or so!
(3) Without the NEW_TASK the OS expects the new activity to follow an existing activity or it will crash your app!